# Order of x (modp) = 3 implies order of x+1 (modp) = 6

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm not sure how to prove the statement. I know that $ord(x)=3$ implies that $p | (x^3-1)$ and $x^3-1 = (x^2+x+1)(x-1)$ and I also know that $ord(x) | (p-1)$, so p is of the form $3k+1$ for $k$ being some integer. I don't know how to use this to show that $ord(x+1) = 6$.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

As $p$ can't divide $x-1,$ it must divide $x^2+x+1$

$x+1\equiv -x^{-1}\pmod p$

Comment: @user328442, Also   $$(x+1)^2\equiv x\pmod p$$